# Why async observer comes to loop?

Tags: angular, angular8

In template I use  async pipe:

```
  {{ constructionObjectsDataService.findbycadnum$() | async }}
```

Service is:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ConstructionObjectsDataService {
      public findbycadnum$ = (): Observable<any> => {
        return this.httpClient.get(
          `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.URL_PATH}/findbycadnum`,
          {
            params: HttpParamsBuilder.buildQueryParams(
              this.parametersService.constructionObjectDataParameters
                .findbycadastnumberParams
            ),
          }
        );
      };

}
```

Why I get loop of requests to the server using:

```
 {{ constructionObjectsDataService.findbycadnum$() | async }}
```

Comment: You really don’t want to have this method call inside your template. Angular will basically keep calling this function with every detection cycle, and its keeps returning new observables..

Comment: How to be then? If I want to use asyn pipe to subscribe and get data from service?

Comment: This doesn’t have to be a function at all. You can simply set up the http call in the service as a const. Or you could (inside the component where you inject the service) set up a const that calls that function once on creation or in ngOnInit, and then in your template do the async subscribe on that const.

Comment: Could you share an sample, what do you mean using my case?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your discussion. I can remove my answer if you @MikeOne give him another one.

Comment: Alice - I’m on the move at the moment so on my phone. Bit hard to give a good code example.

Comment: Vhbazan - up to the OP to decide that :-) - however, I think Alice is trying to prevent calling it multiple times..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here have an example where every second the time parameter gets updated from a "async" (mocked) function:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: "<div> Time: {{ time | async }}</div>"
})
export class AppComponent {
  time = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
  });
}
```

Is that the behaviour you are looking for?

You can see that working on this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-elion-1eb8j?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

**Update**

If you want to call it  when the Component load and then every time you decide to, you can subscribe to another method (pullData()) and call that method every time you would like to "refresh" the data:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <div>Time: {{ findbycadnum }}</div>
    <button (click)="pullData()">Update Value</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  findbycadnum; 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pullData().subscribe(res => {
      this.findbycadnum = res;
    },
    err => {
      console.log('ERROR', err);

    });
  }

  pullData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.URL_PATH}/findbycadnum`,
      {
        params: HttpParamsBuilder.buildQueryParams(
          this.parametersService.constructionObjectDataParameters
            .findbycadastnumberParams
        ),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I hope it helps. (I haven't tested it because of your customised http request can't be tested in that sandbox)

Comment: How to be if I want recall this pipe? When parameters requests are changed?